# Initializing a class with numpy array question

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have defined the following function to be entered into a class:

```
MatrixConverter(arr)
```

Which works exactly how I want it to, taking in a numpy array as argument, and produces a simpler matrix as a numpy array.

Now, I would like to define a class that is initialized by a numpy array, and once I enter a matrix into the class, called SeveralConvertor, to run the entered matrix through `MatrixConverter`, thus creating an internal representation of the converted matrix. My attempt at this goes as follows:

```
class SeveralConvertor:
    def __init_(self,matrix)
    self.matrix=np.array(matrix)

def MatrixConverter(self)
```

Letting `q` be some random array, and then typing `q.MatrixConverter` gives the following error:

```
<bound method SeveralConverter.MatrixConverter of <__main__.SeveralConverter object at 0x7f8dab038c10>>
```

Now, as I said, the function `MatrixConverter(arr)` works fine as a function, but when I entered it into the class, I exchange all `arr` for `self`, which might have something to do with the problem.

Help would be much appriciated!

Comment: `q.MatrixConverter` doesn't _call_ this method, so the expression evaluates to the `bound method SeveralConverter.MatrixConverter` itself. It has nothing to do with NumPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do anything too fancy, we can bind the (unit tested) function to a class method, then invoke that in the `__init__` function.

```
def matrixConverter(arr):
    # Some complicated function you already wrote
    raise NotImplementedError

class SeveralConverter:
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = self._MatrixConverter(matrix)
    
    @staticmethod
    def _MatrixConverter(arr):
        """ Call the Matrix Converter Function """
        return MatrixConverter(arr)
```

Then in your code (put the above in a module and import the class)

```py
matrix_converted = SeveralConverter(ugly_matrix)
print(matrix_converted.matrix)  # Prints the converted matrix
```

Comment: @M Kupperman Thank you very much for your comment! However, two errors occur: When I let x be some np.array and then type SeveralConverter(x), it yields "name 'SeveralConverter' is not defined". Sorry for the inconvenience, I am quite new to python.

Comment: The general workflow for a script (no modules/importing user code) looks like:
1. Implement function. 2. Implement class. 3. Call class. We need to see code to debug.

Comment: @M Kupperman this ended up working, forgot a small "_". Thank you very much!